# How to select all text in string outside of two specific phrases? - SQL

Tags: sql, string, amazon-redshift

I have a column full of strings. I want to select all text in each string outside of the following phrases:  `/***` `***/`

Input:

```
my_strings
A /*** random words here ***/ B C D E H
P /*** ewofneowi ewoifn::123 ewofin wowefn ***/ G H D K
```

Desired Output:

```
A B C D E H
P G H D K
```

I feel like the easiest way to do this would be through RegEx. I'm trying to do something like `regexp_replace()`, and replacing what's between the two delimiters with an empty string (`''`), but can't get this to work. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: which kind of DB is this (MS SQL, Oracle...)?

Comment: It's Redshift DB

Comment: I don't know the syntax of Redshift DB, but here is a possibility in MS SQL, maybe this helps you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d52957fbce5b195a53be1ad2e031df5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the author of this question already successfully tested this from my comment, I will add it here to make it easier to find if someone else has the same question.
Main idea:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(yourcolumn, charindex('/***', yourcolumn) - 1), 
SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, charindex('***/', yourcolumn) +4 , 
LEN(yourcolumn)))
FROM yourtable;
```

Example usage: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d52957fbce5b195a53be1ad2e031df5)